# Not retrieving data from Gridview to Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

The only display in the excel file is the column name and not the data came from the Gridview.

Here are my Functions

```
 private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Function that called the data from SQL

```
    private void Details()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID like " + txtCustomerID.Text, cn);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        gvHistory.DataSource = dt;


    }
```

This is my code in button to save as excel file the data from GridView.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
            ToCsV(gvHistory, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the select statement

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID like '%" + txtCustomerID.Text + "%'"
```

Further to that, you might want to look at using [DataAdapter Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha.aspx) to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)